# How do I get a PTX file to execute

Tags: cuda, nvcc, ptx

I know how to generate a `.ptx` file from a `.cu` and how to generate a `.cubin` file from a `.ptx.` But I don't know how to get the final executable.

More specifically, I have a `sample.cu` file, which is compiled to `sample.ptx`. I then use nvcc to compile `sample.ptx` to `sample.cubin`. However, this `.cubin` file cannot be directly executed without host code. How can I link `.cubin` file to my original `.cu` file to produce the final executable?

Comment: The answer you had accepted is not actually an answer to your question.

Comment: @einpoklum: no it is the answer to his question. You apparently just don't know about a feature that has existed in CUDA since its first release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to run ptx code directly from the cuda driver api with cuModuleLoadDataEx. There is an example [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_0/docs/NVIDIA_FermiCompatibilityGuide.pdf) at page 5

Answer (score 2):

As of CUDA 4.0, you can write inline PTX in CUDA kernels.